# C# fileContents turns into string when downloading a file which ruins the content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, download, blob

I am trying to download a file using ASP.NET MVC and axios.

The problem is that when I return the file in a json object the `fileContents` attribute turns to a string meaning I cannot convert that into a blob to then save it.

When I return the file directly without using the `return Json()` syntax, I get the contents of the file as a string in the front end, losing the `FileDownloadName` which contains the extension of the file that I want to download.

Here is how I try to do the return of the file in a Json object.

```
fileToDownload = new FileContentResult(fileBytes,System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet)
                {
                    FileDownloadName = fileNameWithExtension
                };
//fileBytes is of type byte[]

return Json(fileToDownload);
```

In the front end:

```
$.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: 'mydownloadurl',
               data: uploadFileFormData ,
                success:  (data)=> {
                     //creating blob 
                      var blob = new Blob([data.fileToDownload.fileContents], { type: "application/octetstream" });
                      //getting the file name from the json
                      const fileName = data.fileToDownload.fileDownloadName                     
                    //checking to see if they are using internet explorer
                      var isIE = false || !!document.documentMode;
                    if (isIE) {
                        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob,fileName);
                    } else {
                        var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                        link = url.createObjectURL(blob);
                        var a = $("<a />");
                        a.attr("download",  fileName);
                        a.attr("href", link);
                        $("body").append(a);
                        a[0].click();
                        $("body").remove(a);
                    }
                },
                error: (data) => {
                    console.log("IN ERROR")
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData:false,
            })
```

In the back end, the `fileBytes` is a byte array. But in the front end when I do a `console.log(typeof data.fileToDownload.fileContents)`, it logs a random string. E.g. `k1jghk1h341f2kdfk123rg1`.

If I was to return the File directly then the `data` parameter will be a string which matches exactly the content of the file I am trying to download.E.g. "Column1|Potatos,tomatoes" etc. Also I would run this code in the `success` function:

```
var blob = new Blob([data], { type: "application/octetstream" });
                      
let fileName = "Result.csv"
fileUploadedStyle.path = data.resultPath

var isIE = false || !!document.documentMode;

if (isIE) {
     window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob,fileName);
} else {
     var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
     link = url.createObjectURL(blob);
     var a = $("<a />");
     a.attr("download",  fileName);
     a.attr("href", link);
     $("body").append(a);
     a[0].click();
     $("body").remove(a);
}
```

My end goal is, to be able to bring the file content to the front end with the `FileDownloadName` and then download the file using a blob or any other method you can suggest.

Any parsing of the file content that I need to do is acceptable and please let me know if it is necessary.

I have been searching for the past 3 days for a proper answer but I just can't seem to find something that satisfies my use case.

PS: any help is appreciated. I have seen posts whose answers bash them with how to improve the question or the correct place to put some text which are very critical. Please only focus on answering the question at hand.

Comment: Did you find the answer for it? I am returning FileResult from asp.net mvc 6 webapi2 which returns json object like 
`{
    "FileContents": "",
"ContentType": "",
"FileDownloadName": ""
}`
and on the other side I have a python api client which gets this response but I cant find a way how to store the response as an actual excel file. Tried to store response.content then response.content['FileContents'] and used it as a string and then as bytearray etc. but nothing is working! Tried to call api from C# code also but somehow thats also not working!